# WordPress php insert in php echo a href

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like insert a php code in php echo, but code is not working. Can You help my, please?

My code

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) {
    echo'<div class="article-share">
        <ul class="social-list">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()) ?>" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-facebook-f fa-w-9" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="facebook-f" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 264 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M76.7 512V283H0v-91h76.7v-71.7C76.7 42.4 124.3 0 193.8 0c33.3 0 61.9 2.5 70.2 3.6V85h-48.2c-37.8 0-45.1 18-45.1 44.3V192H256l-11.7 91h-73.6v229"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" aria-hidden="true"></i> --></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()) ?>&amp;via=" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-twitter fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="twitter" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M459.37 151.716c.325 4.548.325 9.097.325 13.645 0 138.72-105.583 298.558-298.558 298.558-59.452 0-114.68-17.219-161.137-47.106 8.447.974 16.568 1.299 25.34 1.299 49.055 0 94.213-16.568 130.274-44.832-46.132-.975-84.792-31.188-98.112-72.772 6.498.974 12.995 1.624 19.818 1.624 9.421 0 18.843-1.3 27.614-3.573-48.081-9.747-84.143-51.98-84.143-102.985v-1.299c13.969 7.797 30.214 12.67 47.431 13.319-28.264-18.843-46.781-51.005-46.781-87.391 0-19.492 5.197-37.36 14.294-52.954 51.655 63.675 129.3 105.258 216.365 109.807-1.624-7.797-2.599-15.918-2.599-24.04 0-57.828 46.782-104.934 104.934-104.934 30.213 0 57.502 12.67 76.67 33.137 23.715-4.548 46.456-13.32 66.599-25.34-7.798 24.366-24.366 44.833-46.132 57.827 21.117-2.273 41.584-8.122 60.426-16.243-14.292 20.791-32.161 39.308-52.628 54.253z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> --></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()) ?>&amp;media=<?php echo $image->guid;?>&amp;description=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_title()); ?>" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" data-pin-do="none" data-pin-custom="true"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-pinterest fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fab" data-icon="pinterest" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 496 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M496 256c0 137-111 248-248 248-25.6 0-50.2-3.9-73.4-11.1 10.1-16.5 25.2-43.5 30.8-65 3-11.6 15.4-59 15.4-59 8.1 15.4 31.7 28.5 56.8 28.5 74.8 0 128.7-68.8 128.7-154.3 0-81.9-66.9-143.2-152.9-143.2-107 0-163.9 71.8-163.9 150.1 0 36.4 19.4 81.7 50.3 96.1 4.7 2.2 7.2 1.2 8.3-3.3.8-3.4 5-20.3 6.9-28.1.6-2.5.3-4.7-1.7-7.1-10.1-12.5-18.3-35.3-18.3-56.6 0-54.7 41.4-107.6 112-107.6 60.9 0 103.6 41.5 103.6 100.9 0 67.1-33.9 113.6-78 113.6-24.3 0-42.6-20.1-36.7-44.8 7-29.5 20.5-61.3 20.5-82.6 0-19-10.2-34.9-31.4-34.9-24.9 0-44.9 25.7-44.9 60.2 0 22 7.4 36.8 7.4 36.8s-24.5 103.8-29 123.2c-5 21.4-3 51.6-.9 71.2C65.4 450.9 0 361.1 0 256 0 119 111 8 248 8s248 111 248 248z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fab fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i> --></a>
            </li>       
            </ul>
    </div></div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: you'll need to explain a bit more. what you are trying to do, what is not working, how it is different from the behavior that you are expecting, if there is any error showing what's the error etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixed up. Make sure you have separate files for CSS and Plain html Code. Once that is complete, Put your code into the PHP Syntax

```
 <?php // PHP code goes here?>
```

and remember to link your php to the css